# Send and receive a file of data as array of integers to a function in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass the array elements to a function which is accessed from a file. But I'm clueless as what's wrong with my declaration,

Here is the code, please help me out.

```
/*This program takes some random data from a file and 
  prepares a histogram for it.
*/

int getdata(int data[],FILE fptr1);

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i,hist[15]={0},elements[15],data[80];
    FILE * fptr1;

    printf("welcome buddy\n");
    getdata(data,fptr1);

    for(i=1;i<80;i++)
        fprintf(stdout,"%2d",data[i]);

}

int getdata(int data[],FILE fptr1)
{
    fptr1=fopen("sampledata.txt","r");

    if(fptr1==NULL)

        printf("the file is not opened properly\n");

    //for(i=0;i<=79;i++)

    //scanf(fptr1,"%d",&data[i]);

    while((scanf(fptr1,"%d",&data)!=EOF))
        ;

    fclose(fptr1);

    return data;
}
```

Comment: data is an integer array.. your array prototype shows return type is an integer. :)

Comment: should  i return it  as data[] ?

Comment: FILE fptr1 -> FILE* fptr1

Comment: @sjsam would you elaborate it please

Comment: You only ever use a `FILE *` in C; you never use a plain `FILE`.  All else apart, the standard says: _The address of the `FILE` object used to control a stream may be significant; a copy of a
`FILE` object need not serve in place of the original._

Comment: Amongst other things: you should not pass an uninitialized `FILE *` to the function; you may as well make the file stream pointer a local variable; you should pass the file name to the function; you should not blunder on after the file fails to open; you should report the error on standard error; your loop passes the same address to `scanf()` each time, so it will overwrite the same space each time; you should not pass `&data` (you probably want `&data[i]` where `i` is a counter from 0); you should pass the length of the array to the function so it doesn't overrun the available space.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
int getdata(int data[],FILE fptr1);
```

to

```
void getdata(int (*data)[80],FILE* f(*data)[80]ptr1)
/* Case 1
 * You need a pointer to 80 member integer array
 * fptr1 is a pointer, a pointer should be passed as a pointer
 */
```

or

```
 void getdata(int data[80],FILE* f(*data)[80]ptr1)
/* Case 2
 * fptr1 is a pointer, a pointer should be passed as a pointer
 */
```

Change

```
(scanf(fptr1,"%d",&data)!=EOF)
```

to

```
(fscanf(fptr1,"%d",data[i])==1) //case1
// data is a pointer,so no ampersand preceeding it
// fscanf returns the number of values filled
```

or

```
(fscanf(fptr1,"%d",&data[i])==1) //case2

// fscanf returns the number of values filled
```

Then remove

```
return data;
```

**Suggestion**

It is good to maintain a count of number of values read, you may put

```
int count=0;
```

in the beginning of the function and then do

```
while((fscanf(fptr1,"%d",&data)==1))
        count++;
```

and replace

```
return data;
```

with

```
return count; // here function return type should be int.
```

In the main function capture the value of count and print the elements till count.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems fine with slight mistakes as below which need to be corrected ::

1. In the getdata function, while reading from file you need to check and make sure it should not read more than 80*4 = 320 bytes from the file otherwise the array will overflow and will corrupt the stack area.
2. In getdata function arguments, FILE should be replaced by FILE* as you are passing a file pointer.
3. You should change the return type of getdata function to void and dont return any value from it.